# Wrapping footnote to second line to fit table in kable (LaTeX .Rmd)

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, footnotes

I'm wondering if there is a way I can force a footnote to fit the width of a table (and wrap to a second line) using `kable` in R (I'm knitting .Rmd to PDF so the format is latex).  I've used both `add_footnote()` and `footnote()`.  The `add_footnote` function will actually wrap a footnote to a second line if it extends beyond the width of the table, but it also forces the use of superscripts (which for this sake is something I can't have in my table).  `footnote` gives me the option to remove the superscript but I'm not sure how to get it to match the formatting of `add_footnote` and wrap footnotes that are wider than the table to a second line.  Another solution would be to remove the superscripts from `add_footnote`

````
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}
```{r packs}
library(pacman)
p_load(tidyverse,knitr,kableExtra,janitor)

mydf <-data_frame(x=1:4,y=2:5,z=3:6)

fn1='This the footnote 1'
fn2='This is footnote 2 and is much longer'

mydf %>%
  kable(format='latex',booktabs=T,
        col.names=c('X','Y','Z'),
        caption=c('This method stretches', 'my table out in an ugly way')) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c('hold_position')) %>%
  footnote(general=c(fn1, fn2),general_title="")

mydf %>%
  kable(format='latex',booktabs=T,
        col.names=c('X','Y','Z'),
        caption=c('This method ruins my title', 'and left justifies my table')) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c('hold_position')) %>%
  footnote(general=c(fn1, fn2),general_title="",threeparttable = T)

mydf %>%
  kable(format='latex',booktabs=T,
        col.names=c('X','Y','Z'),
        caption=c('This is pretty close to perfect', 'if I could remove the superscripts')) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c('hold_position')) %>%
  add_footnote(c(fn1, fn2))
```
````

A screenshot of the knitted PDF:
[image]

Comment: there is a `threeparttable` option

Comment: @Hao Yeah but that ruines my captions/titles and also seems to force my table to be left-justified in the PDF.  I'm admittedly bad at LaTex so I'm guessing fixing the lest justification is simple enough but it just removes parts of my title.  I've edited/attached a MWE above.

Comment: I almost forgot I have such a hack in add_footnote as it was actually using multi-column to do the footnote... Well, in the dev version, for `add_footnote` I added "none" to `notation`. You can try it out.

Comment: No luck.  It gives me an error that I need to use one of `c('alphabet', 'number', 'symbol')`

Comment: “in the dev version” means you need to install from github

Answer (score 4):

setting `threeparttable = TRUE` as @hao suggested worked for me:

```
add_footnote(c(fn1, fn2), threeparttable = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the `notation="none"` option @hao suggested.  It is center-justified.

```
mydf %>%
  kable(format='latex',booktabs=T,
        col.names=c('X','Y','Z'),
        caption=c('Notation="none"') %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c('hold_position')) %>%
  add_footnote(c(fn1, fn2), notation="none")
```

[image]